# Как просканировать JTextField&?

Tags: java, scanner, jtextfield

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Pupcin extends JFrame {
    Scanner sc;
    JTextArea textArea;
    String s;
    eHandler h = new eHandler();
    JButton b1;
    JTextField textField;

    public Pupcin(String a) {
        super("Top Stop");
        JPanel p1 = new JPanel ();
        p1.setSize(200,300);

        textField = new JTextField("Ваше сообщение", 20);
        textField.setCaretColor(Color.GREEN);
        textField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.LEFT);


        textArea = new JTextArea(5, 20);
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        b1 =  new JButton("Ввод");
        b1.setSize(30,50);
        b1.setLocation(100, 200);
        getContentPane().add(textField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        getContentPane().add(textArea);
        textField.add(b1);
        add(p1);
        p1.add(b1);
        b1.addActionListener(h);
        pack();         
    }

    public class eHandler implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if(e.getSource() == b1) {
               sc = new Scanner( (Readable) textField);
               s = sc.nextLine();
              textField.setText(textField.getText() + s);
            }

        }
    }

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        Pupcin win =new Pupcin ("Lalaland");
        win.setVisible(true);
        win.setSize(400,500);
        win.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        win.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте метод `textField.getText()`

---

Для того, чтобы получить текст из JTextField надо вызвать

```
JTextField.getText();
```

если как вы сказали, вам нужно всего лишь продублировать текст 2 раза, то вот так

```
if(e.getSource() == b1) {
   String text = textField.getText();
   textField.setText(text + text);
}
```

Comment: А как? Что именно нужно сделать?

Comment: @George уточните, что именно вы хотите сделать. Я вижу, что вы просто удваиваете текст textField

Comment: Да я собственно говоря и хочу это сделать, но суть в том что у меня ничего не получается. Запустите этот код допустим в эклипсе он выведет ошибку типа(Unknown Source), и укажет на проблему в строчке:          sc = new Scanner((Readable) textArea); и обоснует это так: at Pupcin$eHandler.actionPerformed(Pupcin.java:51)

Comment: класс JTextField не имплементирует интерфейс Readable, поэтому привести его к Readable невозможно. Чтобы получить текст введенный в JTextField надо вызвать метод JTextField.getText()

Comment: слушай ты не мог бы написать все как есть, просто я новичок и не догоняю

Comment: я написал вам, там где вам нужен текст из textField получите его с помощью метода textField.getText(). Тоже самое вы сделали парой строк ниже сканера. Дополнил ответ кодом, который удвоит текст

Comment: Спасибо большое!!

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Pupcin extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5072856842172835145L;
    private final JTextArea textArea;
    private final JTextField textField;
    private final JButton button;

    public Pupcin(String a) {
        super("Top Stop");
        JPanel p1 = new JPanel ();
        p1.setSize(200,300);
        textField = new JTextField("Ваше сообщение", 20);
        textField.setCaretColor(Color.GREEN);
        textField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.LEFT);

        textArea = new JTextArea(5, 20);
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        button =  new JButton("Ввод");
        button.setSize(30,50);
        button.setLocation(100, 200);
        getContentPane().add(textField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        getContentPane().add(textArea);
        textField.add(button);
        add(p1);
        p1.add(button);
        button.addActionListener((java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) -> {
            exitButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        });
        pack();         
    }

    private void exitButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        textField.setText(textField.getText()+textField.getText());
    }   

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        Pupcin win = new Pupcin ("Lalaland");
        win.setVisible(true);
        win.setSize(400,500);
        win.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        win.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```